# How to use AJAX for GET requests in Totaljs?

Tags: total.js

I am using the below code. The AJAX GET is returning status code 500. I am not sure what is missing.

```
<div class="container pt-1" id="usersList">
    <h5>List of Users</h5>
    <div data-bind="users.list__template">
        <ul class="list-group">
        @{foreach user in model}
        <a class="userList" href=/@{user._id}> <li class="list-group-item">@{user.name}</li></a>
        @{end}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 

$('#usersListLink').on('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    AJAX('GET /usersList', 'items --> usersList.items');
    $("#homepage").hide();
    $("#usersList").show();
    $("#addUser").hide();
});
```

Comment: When Ajax is returning 500, that means the backend was not working (in my experience). Try navigating to `/userList` in a web browser to see if you get the same error.

Comment: You should see the error in the console both on the server as well as in the browser. Add it to your question.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Thanks. I navigated to /usersList and fixed the bug. There was an extra pair of braces in my schema. Now I can navigate to /usersList but don't see the data that I am looking for.  Is my AJAX GET syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say just from what you shown.
But on the controllers check the route, it looks it could be flag with some role permits.

```
F.route('/uesrslist', get_platform, ['authorize', '@role']);
```

This could be different depending on how your project is created.